# Woocommerce default sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

When i add this function for sorting featured products first, every other sortings works fine except this one and "Sort by last added products" (it shows same as sort by feautred product)...i found this function, but when i add new product that is not featured it shows it in first place, then i need to change product date to oldest one to show it in last place...is there any chance to make new product last in this sorting?

```
//// WOOCOMMERCE SORTING //////

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'fa_remove_default_sorting_options' );
 
function fa_remove_default_sorting_options( $options ){
 
    unset( $options[ 'popularity' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'menu_order' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'rating' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'date' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'price' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'price-desc' ] );
 
    return $options;
 
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'enable_catalog_ordering_by_modified_date' );
function enable_catalog_ordering_by_modified_date( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        if ( 'featured' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array(
                'orderby'  => 'featured',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            );
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_catalog_orderby_modified_date' );
function add_catalog_orderby_modified_date( $orderby_options ) {
    // Insert "Sort by modified date" and the clone of "menu_order" adding after others sorting options
    return array(
        'featured' => __("Sort by popularity", "woocommerce"),
    ) + $orderby_options ;

    return $orderby_options ;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'default_catalog_orderby_modified_date' );
function default_catalog_orderby_modified_date( $default_orderby ) {
    return 'featured';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'product_query_by_modified_date' );
function product_query_by_modified_date( $q ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && ! is_admin() ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'featured' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
```

Comment: You questions seems to be not clear enough. I have some questions. Do you want the sorting to happen by featured products as the code does it for featured products. 2. Do you want latest products to show first or oldest to show first?

Comment: 1. Yes i want to make a default featured products sorting option.
2. I want products that are not featured to show last.
And my other date sorting not working anymore, when i want to change sort to date, to show me last added product, it wont show, first it shows me featured products instead of last added product.

Comment: Change unset( $options[ 'popularity' ] ); to unset( $options[ 'featured' ] ); to make the featured sorting work. Then tell me what to do next.

Comment: well if i do that i got one more sorting that i deactivated, and thats popularity sorting...it doesnt show featured products..

Comment: okay i fixed my sorting by last added product...but my featured sorting still shows last added product in first place even if its not a featured product..

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code so I can add the featured one there and we can have the complete code there?

Comment: code is the same like above for featured products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the code that's working for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'fa_remove_default_sorting_options' );
 
function fa_remove_default_sorting_options( $options ){
 
    unset( $options[ 'popularity' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'menu_order' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'rating' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'date' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'price' ] );
    //unset( $options[ 'price-desc' ] );
 
    return $options;
 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_catalog_orderby_modified_date' );
function add_catalog_orderby_modified_date( $orderby_options ) {
    // Insert "Sort by modified date" and the clone of "menu_order" adding after others sorting options
    return array(
        'featured' => __("Sort by Featured", "woocommerce"),
    ) + $orderby_options ;

    return $orderby_options ;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'default_catalog_orderby_modified_date' );
function default_catalog_orderby_modified_date( $default_orderby ) {
    return 'featured';
}


function featured_products_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( 'featured' == $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
        $featured_product_ids = (array) wc_get_featured_product_ids();
        if ( count( $featured_product_ids ) ) {
            $string_of_ids = '(' . implode( ',', $featured_product_ids ) . ')';
            $orderby       = "( {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN {$string_of_ids} ) " . $query->get( 'order' );
        }
    }

    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'featured_products_orderby', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'featured_woo_product_query' );
function featured_woo_product_query( $q ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['orderby']) && 'featured' === esc_attr($_GET['orderby']) ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'featured' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
```

Just to let you know, Woocommerce has moved the featured metadata to a taxonomy called `product_visibility`. Hence your code isn't sorting by the meta `featured`

I've tested it, it works fine on my local site.
Let me know if this works for you too.

Comment: my site is https://bizbau.com/ and shop page name is "Trgovina", and if you check, you will see it not showing featured products...and also its not sorted as it was... :/

Comment: i returned like it was before, and you can see my shop page now...its now sorted as i wanted..but the product "test" i last product that i added right now, and it shows in first place instead of featured products...

Comment: That's the reason I'm requesting full code where you have desired sorting already in place then we can add featured sorting to it.

Comment: that is  the only code for sorting that i have..i dont have anything else except that :/

Comment: Strange to notice that it works perfectly fine on my local having only Woocommerce installed with storefront theme and not your website. Could be any other thing overriding the query. You can connect with me directly and we can look directly at your stage environment.

Comment: nope, i checked it..

Comment: Ok, I found the issue with it. The code is working but not as default sorting. 
If we add ?orderby=featured to https://bizbau.com/trgovina 

Which then becomes https://bizbau.com/trgovina/?orderby=featured then it brings featured at the top with the above code. 

For example visit this: https://test.spanrig.com/shop/ first and then https://test.spanrig.com/shop/?orderby=featured. You'll see the difference.

These links will be removed soon and were only created for the testing purpose of this answer.

Comment: So how can i fix that issue

Comment: Are you sure, can you checked it again...i recently deactivated test product...i turn it on again..and i think its not a problem in links..

Comment: Can you check the link I provided? That's the demonstration of code without any additional plugin or theme intervention.

Comment: Same bro...product test shows in both way..withcor without ?orderby=featured

Comment: I'm talking about these URLs:  https://test.spanrig.com/shop first and then https://test.spanrig.com/shop/?orderby=featured. 

Code is implemented there. Test these URLs to understand and confirm the working then we need to find if something is overriding in your theme or plugins.

Comment: Yes i cheked it on your website...but on my website its not woeking with that ?orderby=featured...myb code isnt right

Comment: The same code that I posted above is working on my website without any additional plugins or theme which means your theme or plugins are modifying/overriding the queries and making it not work there.

Comment: You can also set a higher priority to add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'featured_woo_product_query' ); as add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'featured_woo_product_query' , 999); to execute it at the very end of everything. Try this up if this works

You can also try disabling the caching plugins if any, those could also cache the queries and show incorrect results in some cases.

Comment: I just checked these 2 URLs https://bizbau.com/trgovina and https://bizbau.com/trgovina/?orderby=featured and found that it seems to work. I was doing a hard refresh as it was showing cached content.

Comment: it owrks, but can you maybe fix sorting from newst fetarued product date to oldest..

Comment: Can you maybe check this one, we were talking about the link recently, but how can i fix it :/
I tried everything..

Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446243/woocommerce-default-sorting-and-sorting-option-position